# Listview Scrolling blocking when i select Listview item

Tags: android, android-listview

when i select List view item than immediately i am trying to scroll list view but list view scrolling blocked(like UI Blocking) after getting response from web services than it working fine.

And we are using BaseAdpter for list view

Answer (score 0):

> but list view scrolling blocked(like UI Blocking) after getting response from web services than it working fine.

Sounds like you're running your web query on your UI thread.  Doing so causes your UI to lock up until the request is completed, rendering your app useless during the execution of the request as you have noticed.

You'll either have to run your request in a new `Thread` or an `ASyncTask`, to take the load of the UI thread. You can find more info on how to use multiple threads [here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)